# Postfix Catchall Not Working

Tags: postfix, smtp

I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-on-ubuntu-18-04) tutorial to set up Postfix on Ubuntu 18.04. Please assume that the server has an IP address my.ip.add.ress (I've hidden my IP address and email addresses in this post). At this point, if I send an email address to nicholas@my.ip.add.ress, I receive the email in a ~/Maildir directory - it works! Next, I decided to set up a catch-all address, but when I send an email to anything that is not nicholas@my.ip.add.ress, such as info@my.ip.add.ress, the mail log reads as follows:

```
Aug  2 21:50:08 v1 postfix/smtpd[17183]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-lj1-f170.google.com[209.85.208.170]: 550 5.1.1 <info@my.ip.add.ress>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table; from=<myemail@gmail.com> to=<info@my.ip.add.ress> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-lj1-f170.google.com>
```

The highlight is `The Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table`.

For reference, this is `main.cf`:

```
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = v1
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mydestination = localhost
virtual_alias_domains = my.ip.add.ress
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
resolve_numeric_domain = yes
```

The `/etc/postfix/virtual` file reads simply:

```
@my.ip.add.ress nicholas
```

The goal here is that any email that I receive at my.ip.add.ress goes to my local user's mailbox. It feels like I've trawled many solutions, most notably the [official documentation](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html), so any help would be appreciated. I've experimented a lot with `main.cf` - the above is only my last update - but the results have been the same. After any change that I make, I am reloading everything using `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual && sudo postfix reload`, so that should not be a problem either, I think.

EDIT: When I send an email internally (`echo 'init' | s-nail -s 'init' -Snorecord xyz@my.ip.add.ress`), the mail is delivered to my local mailbox. However, if I send the email through Gmail, the email is rejected.

Comment: Take a look in the output of `postconf` for mentions of your IP address in any other configuration parameters, just in case it's been snuck in somewhere unexpected.  Otherwise, the [Postfix debugging howto](http://www.postfix.org/DEBUG_README.html) will almost certainly help you identify your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look through that. I don't know if this helps, but when I send an email internally (`echo 'init' | s-nail -s 'init' -Snorecord xyz@my.ip.add.ress`), the mail is delivered to my local mailbox. However, if I send the email through Gmail, the email is rejected.

Comment: That suggests that either gmail is not connecting to the same mail server as your local delivery attempt, or else your `master.cf` has some sort of special config for your `smtpd` process.

Comment: Did you create a hash from virtual file? _postmap /etc/postfix/virtual_